# How to parse array inside json object in android java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit

how to display array data in json object if the json data is like below. I want to display array data of Ingredient and step. This is the full API Address that I want to fetch the data https://masak-apa-tomorisakura.vercel.app/api/recipe/resep-nasi-bakar-ayam

[image]

I've tried several ways but I can't find how to implement it properly.

this is my json model.

```
@SerializedName("ingredient")
@Expose
Ingredient ingredient = null;


public Ingredient getIngredient() {
    return ingredient;
}

public void setIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}
```

This is the code I use to display the data

```
    public void LoadData() {
    Call<ResultsResponse> call = Config.getInstance().getApi().results(kunci);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResultsResponse> call, Response<ResultsResponse> response) {
            shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
            detailJudul.setText(response.body().getResults().getTitle());
            detailWaktu.setText(response.body().getResults().getTimes());
            detailKesulitan.setText(response.body().getResults().getDificulty());
            detailPorsi.setText(response.body().getResults().getServings());
            detailDeskripsi.setText(response.body().getResults().getIngredient());
            detailAuthor.setText(response.body().getResults().getAuthor().getUser());
            Glide.with(DetailResepActivity.this)
                    .load(response.body().getResults().getThumb())
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(400, 400))
                    .into(detailGambar);

            //Intent Baca Resep di browser
            llVisitWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = ("https://www.masakapahariini.com/resep/" + kunci);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResultsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Hasil", t.getMessage());
        }

    });

    //Intent kembali ke MainActivity
    RelativeLayout ivBack=findViewById(R.id.back);
    ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

This is the error that android studio shows
[image]

[image]

Thanks, I hope someone gives an example project that displays array data in a json object like my problem above.

**UPDATE**

Thanks Gralls, I can display the array data by creating a new string and implementing

```
String ingredient= response.body().getResults().getIngredient().toString();
detailDeskripsi.setText(ingredient);
```

it into the previously created string. Then how to make the data ingredient can be in the form of a list?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an example project but ingredients is array of strings. So instead of having

```
@SerializedName("ingredient")
@Expose
Ingredient ingredient = null;
```

you should parse array into some sort of the list

```
@SerializedName("ingredient")
List<String> ingredient = null;
```

I hope that this will help :)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've solved the problem of displaying the ingredient data by creating a new String and implementing **response.body().getResults().getIngredient().toString()** to the string that was created earlier. Now how to display it in the form of a list? Please see my question, I've edited it

Comment: You can try `String.join("\n",response.body().getResults().getIngredient());` Not 100% sure about this but it should be the easiest way. You can also create some ListView or RecyclerView and display it as normal list.